# append CSV response to existing excel in postman

Tags: excel, csv, append, postman

I made a GET request that gives me a text/csv response. However, i would like to append this to a already existing excel file. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add more details regarding your GET request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can not use external files directly in postman other than for data file. But a work around is to use the visualizer function. Add the below code in your test section**

```
 //Assuming you have your csv content in the variable csv

 csv = `pravz,1
 test,2`
 csv=JSON.stringify(csv)


a =`
<html>
    <body>

        <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
        <pre id="ReadResult"></pre>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function readSingleFile(evt) {
                //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
                var f = evt.target.files[0];
                if (f) {
           
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    r.onload = function (e) {
                        var contents = e.target.result;
                        contents = contents + "\\n" + ${csv}
                        console.log(contents)
                        const blob = new Blob([contents], { type: 'text/plain' });
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('download', "fileName.csv");
a.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
a.click()
                       document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(a);
                    }
                    r.readAsText(f);
                } else {
                    alert("Failed to load file");
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);

        </script>
    </body>

</html>`


pm.visualizer.set(a)
```

**Now goto visualize tab:**

[image]

Just upload the csv file you have , this will append the content to that file and ask where to save the file.

Comment: @DannyVerdel the code assumes you have a two column csv

Comment: create a csv file with two columns same name and age

Comment: then upload that and see if you get the prompt to save the appended file

Comment: change csv = csv = `pravz,1
 test,2` according to your csv wehn using more than two columns

Comment: @Danny please accept this and previous answer by clicking the tick sign :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Generate your text
    input_file = open("text/csv response")
    input_text = input_file.read()

#Opening the excel file to append ("a")    
    f = open("your_file_name.csv","a")

#Write the iput text in the file that you want to be appended  
    f.write(input_text)

#close files otherwise you will get trouble opening them later.    
    f.close()
    input_file.close()
```

Comment: Where do i do this? in the tests?